# Syntax error inserting contents into table

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I keep getting a syntax error and I don't know whats wrong. Can I not call a predetermined string?

```
$sqlstring= "INSERT INTO friends (friend_id , friend_email , password , profile_name , date_started , num_of_friends)
                        VALUES (NULL , $email, $password, $name, CURDATE() , 0);";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `$email, $password, $name` are all varchar or string,you need to wrap themwith single quote.

```
$sqlstring= "INSERT INTO friends (friend_id , friend_email , password , 
                                 profile_name , date_started , num_of_friends)
            VALUES (NULL , '$email', '$password', '$name', CURDATE() , 0)";
```

your query is vunerable with `SQL Injection`, please take time to read the article below to protect from `SQL Injction`

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last semicolon and surround values with quotes.

```
$sqlstring= "INSERT INTO friends (friend_id , friend_email , password , profile_name , date_started , num_of_friends)
                    VALUES (NULL , '$email', '$password', '$name', CURDATE() , 0)";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are accepting user input into your query, it is highly dangerous to simply add it into your SQL statement.

If you are using modern PHP, you would [use PDO to prepare your statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)...

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO friends (friend_id , friend_email , password , profile_name , date_started , num_of_friends)
                    VALUES (NULL , ?, ?, ?, CURDATE() , 0)');
$sth->execute(array($email, $password, $name));
```

Or if you want to stick old school, escape them:

```
$sqlstring = sprintf('INSERT INTO friends (friend_id , friend_email , password , profile_name , date_started , num_of_friends) VALUES (NULL , %s, %s, %s, CURDATE() , 0)',
    mysql_real_escape_string($email),
    mysql_real_escape_string($password),
    mysql_real_escape_string($name)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your updated Query is:

```
$sqlstring = "INSERT INTO friends (friend_id , friend_email , password , profile_name , date_started , num_of_friends) VALUES (NULL , '$email', '$password', '$name', CURDATE() , 0)";
```

---